# Spiner обрезается dialogfragment

Tags: java, android

Я думаю вот эта картинка все объяснит. Конечно можно увеличит размер DialogFragment но может можно как то по другому?
Просили код приложить прикладываю
Разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".view.dialogFragment.FilterDialog3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="500dp"
    android:minHeight="200dp"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Жанры"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinGenres"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/item_chanel"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:ms_background_color="@color/gray_spiner"
        app:ms_background_selector="@drawable/material_spinner_selector"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:ms_dropdown_height="wrap_content"
        app:ms_dropdown_max_height="350dp"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/spinCountries"
        android:textColor="@color/white3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <requestFocus/>
    </com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Страны"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinCountries"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:ms_background_color="@color/gray_spiner"
        app:ms_background_selector="@drawable/material_spinner_selector"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:ms_dropdown_height="wrap_content"
        app:ms_dropdown_max_height="350dp"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/spinYears"
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/spinGenres"
        android:textColor="@color/white3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Годы"
        android:textColor="@color/white3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinYears"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:ms_background_color="@color/gray_spiner"
        app:ms_background_selector="@drawable/material_spinner_selector"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:ms_dropdown_height="wrap_content"
        app:ms_dropdown_max_height="350dp"
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/spinCountries"
        android:textColor="@color/white3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Сам DialogFragment:

```
 public class FilterDialog3 extends DialogFragment implements FilterView {

    @BindView(R.id.spinGenres)
    MaterialSpinner spinGenres;
    @BindView(R.id.spinCountries)
    MaterialSpinner spinCountries;
    @BindView(R.id.spinYears)
    MaterialSpinner spinYears;
    FilterPresenter presenter;
    List<String> years;
    List<String> countries ;
    List<String> genres;;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        presenter = new FilterPresenter();
        presenter.onCreate(this);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog3, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        presenter.getgenres();
        presenter.getcountries();
        presenter.getyears();
        spinGenres.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    //spinGenres.expand();
                    spinGenres.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
                } else {
                    spinGenres.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.color.background_));
                }
            }
        });
        spinYears.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    //spinYears.expand();
                    spinYears.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
                } else {
                    spinYears.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.color.background_));
                }
            }
        });
        spinCountries.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    //spinCountries.expand();
                    spinCountries.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
                } else {
                    spinCountries.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.color.background_));
                }
            }
        });
       spinGenres.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
               L.i("spinGenres is working yraaa!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
               if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){
                   if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                       spinGenres.expand();
                       spinGenres.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
                   }
               }

               return false;
           }
       });
    }

    @Override
    public void setYears(List<ResultYear> years) {
        this.years = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ResultYear ry : years) {
            for(String ry2 : ry.getYear()) {
                this.years.add(ry2);
            }
        }
        spinYears.setItems(this.years);
    }

    @Override
    public void setGenres(List<ResultGenre> genres) {
        this.genres = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ResultGenre ry : genres) {
            for(String ry2 : ry.getGenres()) {
                this.genres.add(ry2);
            }
        }
        spinGenres.setItems(this.genres);
        focusFilter(spinGenres);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCountries(List<ResultCountry> countries) {
        this.countries = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ResultCountry ry : countries) {
            for(String ry2 : ry.getCountry()) {
                this.countries.add(ry2);
            }
        }
        spinCountries.setItems(this.countries);
    }

    public void focusFilter(MaterialSpinner spin) {
        spin.requestFocus();
        spin.setActivated(true);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может код какой-то приложите? или по картинке гадать?

Comment: я приложил код   фрагмента и разметки

Comment: так вы не системный спиннер юзаете) попробуйте системный виджет, потому что библиотечные может себя вести как-то криво в вашем случае

Comment: Спасибо. Надо попробовать хорошая мысль, пока только мысль была на кнопки все спинеры поменять и выводить еще 1 dialogfragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне правильно подсказали, наверное дело в библиотеке, или я что то сделал не правильно в любом случае я поменял MaterialSpinner на Spinner и прекратило обрезаться:

```
<Spinner
        style="@style/spinnerItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/spinGenres"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/spinCountries"
        android:textColor="@color/white3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
        >
        <requestFocus/>
    </Spinner>
```